# Running Business Objects Data Integrator from the command line

Tags: business-objects

I am using the Business Objects Data Integrator tool and I want to run it from the command line so I can setup some automated unit testing.

Does anyone know if there is a command line to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 
http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/xir2acc/en/DIAdministratorGuide.pdf

Perhaps pp65-66 are what you want?  I confess to never having tried it myself, but it looks like it should work. :)